# CSS Animation Slide in and out

Tags: css, animation

I have a green panel sliding in from left to right (works fine) with this:

```
.panel#search {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.56, 1);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.panel#search:target {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

When that green panel is displayed, there is a search link. Clicking on it would display a blue panel sliding in from right to left, like so:

```
.panel#results {
  background-color: #84ceeb;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.56, 1);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}

.panel#results:target {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

However, when clicking on search from the green panel, there is no sliding effect of the blue panel. It displays the blue panel instantly instead of sliding from right to left.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/TheHiddenSoul/pen/KxQwgV)

Comment: Please add a code snippet and don't insert the link as code, it can't be clicked from here. If possible use an embedded codesnippet which can be ran in this post (ctrl-m while making a post or the icon right of the image insert)

Comment: First thing I'm noticing in the code is duplicate IDs in the HTML. First go and avoid that, it might already fix the issue.

Comment: @Grenther, amended. Looking into embedded codesnippet.

Comment: @Grenther, For the duplicate id in the html, I think you mean id="#home". Amended but issue persists.